# Tomcat saving file gives exception

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to save an uploaded file to my disk like this:

```
   Part filePart = req.getPart("pic");
    String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
    InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();

    File uploads = new File("/images/gin");
    File file = new File(uploads, fileName);
    if(!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();
    Files.copy(fileContent, file.toPath());
```

Tomcat always gives me the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
    com.springapp.mvc.servlets.AddItemServlet.doPost(AddItemServlet.java:39)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I don't know why it isn't working. Someone that can help me?

Comment: add file extension e.g.    ".png" ,".jpg"

Comment: Still the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `uploads.mkdirs();` before the new file creation

```
 mkdirs()

 * Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any
 * necessary but nonexistent parent directories.  Note that if this
 * operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary
 * parent directories.
```

Comment: I've just added that before my if test. Still the same problem.

Comment: Found the problem. On osx you need permission to create a folder on the / so I switched it to my home map and that solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check with `uploads.getAbsolutePath()` to see if it's mapping the relative path to the intended folder. If yes, see if the account running tomcat has read/write access to the folder.

Comment: The map doesn't exist yet. So Maybe that's why it doesn't work.